# Subsets of Properties With Spring

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have a properties file with contents looking like this:

```
local.jndi.datasource = localDataSource
dev.jndi.datasource = devDataSource
test.jndi.datasource = testDataSource
prod.jndi.datasource = prodDataSource
```

I have system variables called "app.configDir" and "app.environment". The app.environment variable can be "local","dev","test", or "prod".

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:#{systemProperties['app.configDir'] }/>
```

However, I would like to have the properties narrowed down to the subset defined in the environment variable.

Is there a relatively easy way to do this in XML configuration? I can think of a couple of ways to do this if I were able to use programatic configuration.

Edit: Currently using Spring 3.1.

Comment: Is it an option for you to use a separate properties file for each environment? If yes, you could use something like <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database-${app.environment}.properties"/>

Comment: Unfortunately, I have been told "yea verily, we shall do it this way".

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use spring profiles as of Spring 3.1. so in your config you can have multiple  and place the

```
<beans profile="local">
    <context:property-placeholder  order="1"  location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/some.properties"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="dev">    
    <context:property-placeholder order="1"  location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/someOther.properties"/>
</beans>
```

see the following link for a full example on using Spring profiles:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml

Answer (score 0):

In XML in Spring 3.1 you can do this:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>${app.configDir}</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

This will enable a profile (dev/test/prod), but first define the beans using the profile:

```
<beans profile="dev">
  <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:update.sql" />
  </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>

<beans profile="qa">
  <bean id="dataSource"

    ￼class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:url="jdbc:h2:tcp://dbserver/~/mydb"
    p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
    p:username="sa"
    p:password="password"
    p:initialSize="20"
    p:maxActive="30" />

</beans>
```